# Converting from grades to gpa (with decimal)

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have this code:

```
int[][] stuGrades = {{97, 64, 75, 100, 21}}; //extract from data file

String[][] HWdata; // original data file
for (int g = 0; g < stuGrades.length; g++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < stuGrades[0].length; p++) {
        int tempScores = stuGrades[g][p];
        if (tempScores <= 100 && tempScores > 98.1) {
            stuGpa[g][p] = 4.0;
        }
        else if (tempScores <= 98 && tempScores > 96.1) {
            stuGpa[g][p] = 3.9;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to convert the grades array `{97, 64, 75, 100, 21}` to a new GPA array, which will convert the score to 4.0, 3.9 or something else. I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at homework7.main.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't point at nothing. I give specific value to it.

Comment: 1. Do you perhaps have a stacktrace for us?  
2. Is it possible that you never initialized `stuGpa` or  `HWdata`?

Comment: I set both stuGpa and HWdata are null, but HWdata is used to storage data from a file. then I use stuGpa to collect the HWdata I need. I debug HWdata, the data was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't initialized `stuGpa` correctly as MalumAtire832 pointed out.

```
int[][] stuGrades = {{97, 64, 75, 100, 21}}; //extract from data file

double[][] stuGpa = new double[stuGrades.length][stuGrades[0].length];

String[][] HWdata; // original data file
for (int g = 0; g < stuGrades.length; g++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < stuGrades[0].length; p++) {
        int tempScores = stuGrades[g][p];
        if (tempScores <= 100 && tempScores > 98.1) {
            stuGpa[g][p] = 4.0;
        } else if (tempScores <= 98 && tempScores > 96.1) {
            stuGpa[g][p] = 3.9;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. It did help me understand my mistake. I declare the array of stuGpa before my data array.

Comment: Correct! An array has a fixed size!